# Output from batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, output

I have a daily script to sync files to S3 bucket in AWS :

```
cd "C:\ProgramData\Console\Patches" & aws s3 sync . s3://distribution/Patches
```

I want it so that the outputs of the script will be saved to a new log file, for example: `C:\Logs`.

Which command do I need need to add?

Comment: Please read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) or [How-to: Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just redirect the output to a file.

```
cd "C:\ProgramData\Console\Patches" & aws s3 sync . s3://distribution/Patches >> aws-patches.log 2>&1
```

`>` creates a new file every time
`>>` creates or appends
`2>&1` redirects error-out to std-out, so you also get the errors in the log